# How to sort two HashMap which has common key?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two **HashMap** which look like this,

```
public HashMap<Integer, String> scoreName = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
public HashMap<Integer, Integer> scoreValue = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Here both **HashMap** has common key. I want to sort scoreValue **HashMap** and scoreName **HashMap** where scoreName **HashMap** should also be sorted according scoreValue.

Example:

scoreValue = 5,1,7,7,9
scoreName = a, b , c, d,e

after sorting scoreValue = 1,5,7,7,9
      sorting scoreName = b,a,c,d,e

I can sort my scoreValue

```
   List sortedKeys = new ArrayList(scoreValue.values());
   Collections.sort(sortedKeys);
```

but this is not the solution that I am looking for !

Comment: Hashmaps do not have an ordering. Do you want to extract the values and sort those?

Comment: Look for a different implementation of `Map`, that maintains ordering. Moreover, the one that keeps the key sorted.

Comment: I couldn't understand need of two maps.

Comment: Could you explain what are the keys and values of your maps? Please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

`HashMaps` are unordered collections, so you cannot sort them.

What would be better here is to have a `Score` object which contains the key, name and value as member variables.

Then just have a simple `List<Score>` and then call `Collections.sort()` on the list.

If you need the fast id look-up as well then you can have as `HashMap` of id to `Score`. Iterate over the list when you need them in order. Look them up in the map to find the score and name for a given id.

If each `Score` object wants to know it's ranking in the list then you can loop through the sorted collection after doing the sort and have a variable in the `Score` object to store that as well.

TreeMap/TreeSet might also be helpful in this case but they don't allow random access (i.e. who is at position 3) and TreeMap sorts based on the key in the map, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap has no ordering of any sort. You can use a LinkedHashMap or you can use trees (or data structures similar to trees). Using a LinkedHashMap is very similar to using a HashMap.